# What's the Django 1.7+ equivalent to South's add_ignored_fields()?

Tags: django, migration, django-south, django-1.7

Back in previous versions of Django, we all used South to do migrations, and because it wasn't as smart as we might have liked, we sometimes needed to tell it to explicitly ignore some fields because such fields were too complicated for it to handle.  We did this with `add_ignored_fields` and everything pretty much worked.

In our case, we have a "field" on our model that's a subclass of `CharField` that actually attaches two additional fields to the model via the `contribute_to_class` method.  It's kind of a weird process, but it makes sense for our use case and worked just fine until we upgraded to Django 1.7.

However, with the new migrations system, our use of `add_ignored_fields()` no longer works and our unit tests are exploding as it tries to create a test database table with these fields.  Specifically it says:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: duplicate column name: our_column_name
```

In this case `our_column_name` is one of the fields this special CharField subclass creates.

In a perfect world, we could have the migration code handle these fields properly, but I'd settle for the 1.7 version of `add_ignored_fields()` if it exists.

I should also point out that we've found [the explanation for `deconstruct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#custom-deconstruct-method) in the Django documentation, but I'm afraid that it doesn't make any sense to me.  I can't figure out if it applies to this situation or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've discovered [this Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22555) that pretty much states that this is a design pattern that the devs aren't supporting, so we're just going to have to rewrite the model to explicitly create the other fields on the model and then reference said fields from the "parent" field a la `ImageField`.