# How to ignore migration of custom fields in Django 1.7.1?

Tags: python, django, migration

How to ignore migration of custom fields in Django 1.7.1?

In earlier versions South had the following syntax to do it. Any idea on how to do it on Django 1.7 where south is no longer supported.

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_ignored_fields
add_ignored_fields(["VirtualField$"])
```

Comment: Duplicate of [What's the Django 1.7+ equivalent to South's add_ignored_fields()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606178/whats-the-django-1-7-equivalent-to-souths-add-ignored-fields)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. Closing this question in favor of the old question.